# JdbcSQLException for more than 40 tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, h2, mockmvc

Whenever i try executing a test class with more than 40 tests, the excess tests fail.
The test class consists of 43 tests. No matter which three tests i remove, the rest of them runs green.

Frameworks used:

- Junit
- Mockmvc
- h2 database

Stack trace:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
COMMIT [50000-197]
Error Code: 50000

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicRollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.rollbackTransaction(DatasourceAccessor.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.rollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1732)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicRollbackTransaction(AbstractSession.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.basicRollbackTransaction(ClientSession.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.rollbackTransaction(AbstractSession.java:3968)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.rollbackTransaction(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.rollbackTransaction(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.release(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4576)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:559)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:443)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:230)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:228)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:120)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
COMMIT [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:274)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:497)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:457)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:388)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicRollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1743)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:254)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:267)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.unlockAll(Session.java:985)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.endTransaction(Session.java:760)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.commit(Session.java:708)
    at org.h2.command.dml.TransactionCommand.update(TransactionCommand.java:46)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261)
    ... 57 more
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
COMMIT [50000-197]
Error Code: 50000

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicRollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.rollbackTransaction(DatasourceAccessor.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.rollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1732)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicRollbackTransaction(AbstractSession.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.basicRollbackTransaction(ClientSession.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.rollbackTransaction(AbstractSession.java:3968)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.rollbackTransaction(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.rollbackTransaction(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.release(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4576)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:559)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:443)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterEach(SpringExtension.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:230)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:228)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:120)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
COMMIT [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:274)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:497)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:457)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:388)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicRollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1743)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:254)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:267)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.unlockAll(Session.java:985)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.endTransaction(Session.java:760)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.commit(Session.java:708)
    at org.h2.command.dml.TransactionCommand.update(TransactionCommand.java:46)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261)
    ... 57 more
```

Test class head and sample test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [ProductionOrderTestApp::class, JobControllerTestData::class, JPAConfig::class,
    JsonPatchHelper::class, JsonMergePatchHttpMessageConverter::class])
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application_h2.properties"])
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Transactional
class ProductionOrderControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var productionOrderController: ProductionOrderController
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var globalExceptionHandler: GlobalExceptionHandler
    @Suppress("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var genericTestRepository: GenericTestRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var requestMappingHandlerAdapter: RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var productionOrderTestDataCreator: ProductionOrderTestDataCreator
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var productService: ProductService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    private val isoDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").apply {
        timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    }

    @BeforeAll
    fun init() {
        JsonProviderConfig().config()
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(globalExceptionHandler, productionOrderController)
                .setCustomArgumentResolvers(PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
                .setMessageConverters(*requestMappingHandlerAdapter.messageConverters.toTypedArray())
                .setCustomArgumentResolvers(PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
                .build()
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun after() {
        Configuration.setDefaults(DefaultsImpl.INSTANCE)
    }

    // get tests
    @Test
    fun `should return 20 persisted production orders sorted by name ascending without pagination request parameters`()
            : Unit = with(productionOrderTestDataCreator) {
        val generatedProductionOrders = generateProductionOrders(25)
        val mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api/v03/production-orders"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(header().string(X_TOTAL_COUNT, "25"))
                .andExpect(header().string(
                        HttpHeaders.LINK,
                        """</api/v03/production-orders?page=1&size=20>; rel="next",</api/v03/production-orders?page=1&size=20>; rel="last",</api/v03/production-orders?page=0&size=20>; rel="first""""))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.length()").value(20))
                .andReturn()

        val orders: List<ProductionOrderResource> = mapper.readValue(mvcResult.response.contentAsByteArray,
                object : TypeReference<List<ProductionOrderResource>>() {})

        assertThat(orders).containsExactlyElementsOf(generatedProductionOrders.sortedBy { it.name }
                .subList(0, 20).map { it.toResource() })
    }
```

application_h2.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:xeticslean;MODE=MSSQLServer;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=0;mv_store=false;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=30000
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.weaving=true
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.logging.level=SEVERE
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.ddl-generation=drop-and-create-tables
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size=500
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing=jdbc
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.cache.shared.default=false
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.target-database=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode=commit
```

When a local mssql database was used instead of the h2 database, all tests were green.
I'm looking for a clue on how to make this work regardless of the database used.

Comment: Take a look at this issue from h2, it might help you: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1200

Comment: What is the `h2` version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

H2 1.4.197 is an old and unsupported version.

The combination of `MV_STORE=FALSE` with `MVCC=TRUE` was always experimental only and had many bugs. If you want to use the new storage engine, remove both these settings from the URL. If you want to use the legacy storage engine (it is typically pointless for in-memory databases, but you may have some own reasons), use `MV_STORE=FALSE` and `MVCC=FALSE` in this version.

`MVCC` setting was removed since then and recent versions of H2 don't have it any more. New engine always uses row-level locks, old engine (`MV_STORE=FALSE`) always uses table-level locks in them.